How to avoid changing date format columns from xlsx file to synapse parquet using SFTP
I have xlsx file with these columns:



Vendor_ID
Vendor_Name
Vendor_Birthday




SMCAI_01
Ely Cruz
08/06/1984


SMCAI_02
Luzvi Ching
11/12/1969


SMCAI_03
Lucy Ford
01/03/1991



However, after copying the file to synapse table, the parquet result became like this:



Vendor_ID
Vendor_Name
Vendor_Birthday




SMCAI_01
Ely Cruz
1984-06-08


SMCAI_02
Luzvi Ching
1969-12-11


SMCAI_03
Lucy Ford
1991-03-01



Vendor SMCAI_01 birthday became June 08, 1984 (YYYY-DD-MM) instead of Aug 06,1984 (YYYY-MM-DD) and for the rest of the vendors after I display the parquet file using databricks.
datefrmt = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
vendor_assoc = (vendor_assoc.withColumn('Vendor_Birthday', f.to_date('Vendor_Birthday', format = datefrmt)))
This is the schema of the columns:
root 
Vendor_ID: string (nullable = true) 
Vendor_Birthday: date (nullable = true) 
Vendor_Name    : string (nullable = true) 
Desire output:
Vendor_Birthday column format is (YYYY-MM-DD)



Vendor_ID
Vendor_Name
Vendor_Birthday




SMCAI_01
Ely Cruz
1984-08-06


SMCAI_02
Luzvi Ching
1969-11-12


SMCAI_03
Lucy Ford
1991-01-03



I wanna know if I can achieve my desire output using sftp or possible using azure databricks?

To get your required output you can follow below procedure:
Read parquet file into data frame using below code:
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("<filePath>") 

Modify the df by extracting year, month, and day from the Vendor_Birthday column.
and reassemble the Vendor_Birthday column correctly by switching the day and month.
Rebuild the column as a valid date in the YYYY-MM-DD format using below code:
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1 = df.withColumn('year', f.split(f.col('Vendor_Birthday'), '-').getItem(0)) \
        .withColumn('day', f.split(f.col('Vendor_Birthday'), '-').getItem(1)) \
        .withColumn('month', f.split(f.col('Vendor_Birthday'), '-').getItem(2))
df1 = df1.withColumn('Vendor_Birthday', f.concat_ws('-', df1['year'], df1['month'], df1['day']))
df1 = df1.withColumn('Vendor_Birthday', f.to_date(f.col('Vendor_Birthday'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df1 = df1.drop('year', 'month', 'day')
df1.show()

It will give the output as shown below:

Write the above df1 into synapse table.

@kimchigirl can you check the answer, does it helpful? let me know it.
